# Computing $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x^{1+\alpha}}\,\mathrm d x$

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory

Let $\alpha\in(0,1)\cup(1,2)$. I want to show that the integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x^{1+\alpha}}\,\mathrm dx$$

- exists (in Lebesgue’s sense: the integral of the absolute value of the integrand is finite); and
- is equal to $$-\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi\alpha}{2})\,\Gamma(2-\alpha)}{\alpha(1-\alpha)},$$ where $\Gamma(t)\equiv\int_0^{\infty}x^{t-1}\exp(-t)\,\mathrm d t$ is Euler’s gamma function, defined for $t>0$.

I am thinking about a clever transformation and then applying Fubini’s theorem, but I’m stuck at this point. Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Let $I(\alpha)$, $0<\alpha<2$, be the integral given by

$$\begin{align}
I(\alpha)&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos ( x  )-1}{x^{1+\alpha}}\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Integrating by parts $(1)$ with $u=\cos(x)-1$ and $v=-\frac{1}{\alpha x^{\alpha}}$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
I(\alpha)&=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}\,dx \tag 2\\\\
\end{align}$$

For $1<\alpha <2$, integrating by parts $(2)$ with $u=\sin(x)$ and $v=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}x^{1-\alpha}$ yields

$$\begin{align}
I(\alpha)&=-\frac{1}{\alpha(\alpha-1)}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^{\alpha-1}}\,dx \tag 3\\\\
\end{align}$$

---

> **CASE $1$: $0<\alpha<1$**

Note that for $0<\alpha<1$, we can write $(2)$ as

$$I(\alpha)=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\text{Im}\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x^\alpha}\,dx\right) \tag 4$$

Enforcing the substitution $x\to ix$ in the integral on the right-hand sides of $(4)$ yields

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x^\alpha}\,dy=e^{i\pi (1-\alpha)/2}\int_0^{-i\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^\alpha}\,dx \tag 5$$

Using Cauchy's Integral Theorem, we can deform the contours back to the real line and write $(5)$ as

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x^\alpha}\,dx&=e^{i\pi (1-\alpha)/2}\int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha}e^{-x}\,dx\\\\&=e^{i\pi (1-\alpha)/2}\Gamma(1-\alpha) \tag 6
\end{align}$$

Substituting $(6)$ into $(4)$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos ( x  )-1}{x^{1+\alpha}}\,dx&=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\sin((1-\alpha)\pi/2)\Gamma(1-\alpha)\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\cos(\pi \alpha/2)\Gamma(1-\alpha) \tag 7\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{-\frac{1}{\alpha(1-\alpha)}\cos(\pi \alpha/2)\Gamma(1-\alpha) } \tag 8
\end{align}$$

where in going from $(7)$ to $(8)$ we used the functional relationship $\Gamma(1+z)=z\Gamma(z)$.

---

> **CASE $2$: $1<\alpha<2$**

Note that for $1<\alpha<2$, we can write $(3)$ as

$$I(\alpha)=-\frac{1}{\alpha(\alpha -1)}\text{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x^{\alpha-1}}\,dx\right) \tag 9$$

Enforcing the substitution $x\to ix$ in the integral on the right-hand side of $(9)$ yields

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x^{\alpha-1}}\,dx=-e^{-i\pi \alpha/2}\int_0^{-i\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha-1}}\,dx \tag {10}$$

Using Cauchy's Integral Theorem, we can deform the contour back to the real line and write $(10)$ as

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x^{\alpha-1}}\,dx&=-e^{i\pi \alpha/2}\int_0^\infty x^{1-\alpha}e^{-x}\,dx\\\\&=-e^{i\pi \alpha/2}\Gamma(2-\alpha) \tag{11}
\end{align}$$

Substituting $(11)$ into $(9)$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos ( x )-1}{x^{1+\alpha}}\,dx=-\frac{1}{\alpha(1-\alpha)}\cos(\alpha\pi/2)\Gamma(2-\alpha) }\tag {12}
\end{align}$$

---

> **PUTTING IT ALL TOGETHER:**
>
> Using $(8)$ and $(12)$ along with the well-known result $I(1)=\pi/2$, we find that for all $0<\alpha<2$ we have
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos ( x  )-1}{x^{1+\alpha}}\,dx=-\frac{1}{\alpha(\alpha-1)}\cos(\alpha\pi/2)\Gamma(2-\alpha)}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: you don't give any justification for $\int_0^\infty \sin(x) x^{-\alpha} dx = \Gamma(1-\alpha) \cos(\pi \alpha / 2)$ ?  (when $Re(\alpha) \in (0,2)$)

Comment: @Dr.MV I’m not very familiar with contour integration on the complex plane. I was ideally looking for a method using Lebesgue integration on the line invoking Fubini’s theorem. At any rate, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @triple_sec You're welcome.  My pleasure!  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

Based on the deleted answer by @Jack D'Aurizio, I can construct a proof based on Fubini’s theorem.

For each $(x,t)\in(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$, define $$f(x,t)\equiv\frac{(1-\cos x)t^{\alpha}\exp(-tx)}{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}.$$ Clearly, $f$ is continuous on its domain and non-negative. Moreover, the Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite on the positive ray $(0,\infty)$. Therefore, Fubini’s theorem applies (as a special case for non-negative functions, usually referred to as Tonelli’s theorem).

For a fixed $x>0$, integrating with respect to $t$ yields:
\begin{align*}
\int_{t\in(0,\infty)}f(x,t)\,\mathrm dt=&\,\frac{1-\cos x}{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}\int_{t\in(0,\infty)}t^{\alpha}\exp(-t x)\,\mathrm d x\overset{s\equiv tx}{=}\frac{1-\cos x}{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}\int_{s\in(0,\infty)}\frac{s^{\alpha}\exp(-s)}{x^{1+\alpha}}\,\mathrm d s\\
=&\,\frac{1-\cos x}{x^{1+\alpha}}
\end{align*}
after substituting and using the definition of the gamma function. This is $-1$ times the integrand in my question. Therefore, the negative of the integral in my question is given as
\begin{align*}
\int_{x\in(0,\infty)}\int_{t\in(0,\infty)}f(x,t)\,\mathrm dt\,\mathrm dx=\int_{t\in(0,\infty)}\int_{x\in(0,\infty)}f(x,t)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dt
\end{align*}
by Tonelli’s theorem.

Now, once can check by differentiation that for each $t>0$, one has
$$\int(1-\cos x)\exp(-t x)\,\mathrm d x=-\frac{\exp(-t x)[1+t^2(1-\cos x)+t\sin x]}{t(1+t^2)}+C$$
for $C\in\mathbb R$. Upon taking limits and simplifying, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\int_{t\in(0,\infty)}\int_{x\in(0,\infty)}f(x,t)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dt=&\,\int_{t\in(0,\infty)}\frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(1+\alpha)(1+t^2)}\,\mathrm dt\overset{s\equiv(1+t^2)^{-1}}{=}\int_{s\in(0,1)}\frac{s^{-\alpha/2}(1-s)^{\alpha/2-1}}{2\Gamma(1+\alpha)}\,\mathrm ds\\
=&\,\frac{B(1-\alpha/2,\alpha/2)}{2\Gamma(1+\alpha)}=\frac{\Gamma(1-\alpha/2)\Gamma(\alpha/2)}{2\Gamma(1)\Gamma(1+\alpha)},
\end{align*}
where $B$ is the beta function.

From here, the interested reader can finish the proof using [Euler’s reflection formula](http://planetmath.org/eulerreflectionformula) (which, to be honest, I’m not familiar and not comfortable operating with) and using the basic properties of trigonometric functions.

---

On a second thought, I like the result
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^{1+\alpha}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\Gamma(1-\alpha/2)\Gamma(\alpha/2)}{2\Gamma(1+\alpha)}\tag{$\spadesuit$}$$ I just derived better than $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^{1+\alpha}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\cos(\pi\alpha/2)\Gamma(2-\alpha)}{\alpha(1-\alpha)},\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ so no further derivation is necessary. One reason is that ($\spadesuit$) is valid even if $\alpha=1$ (in which case the result is $\pi/2$), where the case $\alpha=1$ can only be obtained as a limit under ($\clubsuit$).

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I reformulated your deleted answer almost verbatim, although in a different context. Instead of using Laplace transforms, I appealed directly to Fubini–Tonelli theory. The final result still requires some complex analysis (in so far as the proof of Euler’s reflection formula relies on contour integration, as far as I know), with which I am unfamiliar. Still, I feel that this proof is as good as it gets for my purposes. I think you should formally take credit for this answer (_e.g._, you could copy my answer under your name and I delete mine)—please let me know what you think.